# Problem with return value of the function

Tags: arrays, c, function

The problem statement is given below

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXP 80

char namelist[MAXP][11];
int num_per;
int numquery;

int common_friends(int friends[][MAXP], char name1[], char name2);

int main() {
    int num_pair, i, j, e;
    printf("Enter the number of persons:");
    scanf("%d", &num_per);
    int id[num_per];
    printf("\nEnter %d names\n", num_per);

    for (i = 0; i < num_per; i++) {
        scanf("%s", namelist[i]);
        id[i] = i;
    }

    printf("For corresponding persons the ID are as follows\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_per; i++) {
        printf("The ID of %s is %d\n", namelist[i], id[i]);
    }

    printf("How many friend pairs do you know?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_pair);
    printf("\nEnter the friend pairs\n");

    int friends[MAXP][MAXP];

    for (int g = 0; g < num_per; g++) {
        for (e = 0; e < num_per; e++) {
            friends[g][e] = 0;
        }
    }

    char dumname3[11], dumname4[11];

    for (j = 0; j < num_pair; j++) {
        char dumname1[11], dumname2[11];
        scanf("%s %s", dumname1, dumname2);
        int flag1 = 0;
        int flag2 = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < num_per; i++) {
            if (strcmp(dumname1, namelist[i]) == 0) {
                flag1 = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < num_per; k++) {
                    if (strcmp(dumname2, namelist[k]) == 0) {
                        flag2 = 1;
                        friends[i][k] = 1;
                        friends[k][i] = 1;
                        printf("ok\n");
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (flag2 == 0)
                    printf("%s does not exist\n", dumname2);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (flag1 == 0) {
            printf("%s does not exist\n", dumname1);
        }
    }

    printf("The friends array is below\n");

    for (int erp = 0; erp < num_per; erp++) {
        for (int tut = 0; tut < num_per; tut++) {
            printf("%d ", friends[erp][tut]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Enter the number of queries\n");
    scanf("%d", &numquery);

    for (int z = 0; z < numquery; z++) {
        int alpha;
        printf("Enter query %d\n", z + 1);
        scanf("%s", dumname3);
        scanf("%s", dumname4);

        alpha = common_friends(friends, dumname3, dumname4);

        if (alpha == -1) {
            printf("Either %s or %s or both don't exist\n", dumname3, dumname4);
        } else if (alpha == -2) {
            printf("%s and %s do not have a common friend.\n", dumname3, dumname4);
        } else {
            printf("%s is one common friend of %s and %s\n", namelist[alpha], dumname3, dumname4);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int common_friends(int friends[][MAXP], char name1[], char name2) {
    int frag1 = 0;
    int frag2 = 0;
    int storeval1 = -1, storeval2 = -1;

    for (int p = 0; p < num_per; p++) {
        if (strcmp(namelist[p], name1) == 0) {
            frag1 = 2;
            storeval1 = p;

            for (int u = 0; u < num_per; u++) {
                if (strcmp(namelist[u], name2) == 0) {
                    frag2 = 2;
                    storeval2 = u;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    if (frag1 == 2 && frag2 == 2) {
        for (int r = 0; r < num_per; r++) {
            if (friends[storeval1][r] && friends[storeval2][r]) {
                return r;
            }
        }
        return -2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Here is my code.

My inputs were as follows:

Enter number of persons: 5

Enter 5 names:

Amal

Barun

Chaya

Diya

Esha

How many friend pairs?

4

Enter friend pairs:

Amal Diya

Esha Barun

Chaya Diya

Chaya Esha

How many queries:3

Enter query 1:

Amal Barun

*expected* Amal and Barun do not have a common friend.
*actual*    Diya is the common friend of Amal and Barun.

Enter query 2

Chaya Diya

*expected   *Chaya and Diya do not have a common friend*

actual      *Either Chaya or Diya don't exist.**

Enter query 3

Amal Chaya

*expected* Diya is the common friend of Amal and Chaya
*actual*    same as expected.

Comment: `int common_friends(int friends[][MAXP], char name1[], char name2)` should be giving you warnings. `char name2` is NOT a pointer to a string. Haven't read more than this much...

Comment: Start by setting a high warning level for your compiler. For instance for `gcc` do `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ...` Fix all the warnings (they will appear as errors due to `-Werror`) and then start the debug.

Comment: I'm not a professional programmer.

Comment: Please state the exact issue.

Comment: @VedantSharma You ask: "Please state the exact issue". Well, user Fe2O3 have already told you about an important issue. To be a bit more explicit I'll repeat. This `int common_friends(int friends[][MAXP], char name1[], char name2);` is wrong. You want to pass two strings `name1` and `name2` but for some reason you code differs. Correct it like: `int common_friends(int friends[][MAXP], char name1[], char name2[]);` In other words, `name2` should have array-syntax just like `name1`. BTW: You can also write it like: `int common_friends(int friends[][MAXP], char* name1, char* name2);`

Comment: @VedantSharma Notice that there may be other issues but you should fix this first. If it still doesn't work you can ask another question. If there is **no answer** posted for this question it's also fine to edit this question with the updated code. But in case **an answer has been posted, do not change the question**.